# Foreign key in SQLAlchemy (flask) changing before insert into DB?

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlalchemy, flask

I am trying to use SQLAlchemy to insert some records into a database with a foreign key but the foreign key does not seem to be changing as I would expect.

I have a simple 1-M relationship between two objects, Account & Transaction. The Account objects have been inserted into the database fine but when I try to iterate through these accounts and add transaction objects to them, the foreign key for all of the transactions is the id of the last account being iterated through.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is? it has been driving me crazy!

My account and transaction objects:

```
class Account(db.Model):
    number = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    bsb = db.Column(db.String(80), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    description = db.Column(db.String(80))

class Transaction(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    account_id = db.Column(db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('account.number'))
    amount = db.Column(db.Float(precprecision=2))
```

Here is where I am iterating through the accounts in the DB and trying to add transaction objects to them:

```
def Sync_Transactions():
    #The following definately returns two account objects from the DB
    accounts = [db.session.query(Account).filter(Account.number == '999999999').first(), db.session.query(Account).filter(Account.number == '222222222').first()]

    for acc in accounts:
        #The following parses a CSV file for the account and returns transaction objecs as a list
        transactions = myLib.ParseCsvFile('C:\\transactions_%s.csv' % (acc.number))
        acc.transactions = transactions
        db.session.merge(acc)
    db.session.commit()
```

The above, if only 1 account is retrieved from db, works fine. As soon as I start iterating over multiple accounts all of the transactions get given the same foreign key (the key of the last account - 222222222 in the above case)

**Here is where the issue is**

```
def ParseCsvFile(self, fileLocation, existingTransactionList=[]):
    with open(fileLocation, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,['Date','TransactionAmount','C','D','TransactionType','TransactionDescription','Balance'])
        for row in reader:
            if not row['TransactionDescription'] == '':
                existingTransactionList.append(Transaction(
                    float(row['TransactionAmount'])
                    )
                )
    return existingTransactionList
```

For some reason having the parameter existingTransactionList causes the issue. If I change the above code to the following the problem goes away but I still don't understand why due to my lack of python knowledge I am guessing :)

```
def ParseCsvFile(self, fileLocation, existingTransactionList=[]):
    existingTransactionList=[]
    with open(fileLocation, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f,['Date','TransactionAmount','C','D','TransactionType','TransactionDescription','Balance'])
        for row in reader:
            if not row['TransactionDescription'] == '':
                existingTransactionList.append(Transaction(
                    float(row['TransactionAmount'])
                    )
                )
    return existingTransactionList
```

The reason I have the existingTransactionList variable as a parameter is because I will eventually want to pass in a list of existing transactions and only the unique ones will get returned by using something like the following:

```
transactionList = list(set(existingTransactionList))
```

Comment: Seems like you need to show the ParseCsvFile method.

Comment: Thankyou! the issue was indeed in the ParseCsvFile method but I still don't really know why there was a problem. I have added the code into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding *all* of your transactions to the last account. Change:

```
def ParseCsvFile(self, fileLocation, existingTransactionList=[]):
```

to

```
def ParseCsvFile(self, fileLocation, existingTransactionList=None):
    if existingTransactionList is None:
        existingTransactionList = []
```

#### Why does this happen

Python only parses the declaration for a function *once* and all of the default arguments are bound to their values during this compilation stage.  That means that instead of every invocation of `ParseCsvFile` being given a new list instead every call to `ParseCsvFile` uses the *same* list.

To see what is going on, try the following on the command line:

```
def test_mutable_defaults(value, x=[], y={}):
    print("x's memory id this run is", id(x))
    print("Contents of x", x)
    print("y's memory id this run is", id(y))
    print("Contents of y", y)

    x.append(value)
    y[value] = value

    return x, y
```

then use this function:

```
test_mutable_defaults(1)
test_mutable_defaults(2)
test_mutable_defaults(3)
```

If Python re-evaluated `x` and `y` on each call you would see different memory IDs for each call and `x` would be `[1]`, then `[2]`, then `[3]`.  Because Python only evaluates `x` and `y` when it first compiles `test_mutable_defaults` you will see the *same* memory ID for `x`  each call (and likewise for `y`), and `x` will be `[1]`, then `[1, 2]` and then `[1, 2, 3]`.